# Question deleted by Community

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121149/reversing-of-words) was deleted by Community.
But I can't see why. [Shouldn't it only delete the old/closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Comment: That is really odd. Hm. I think Community's trying to rise up against us :o "We should ban Community, it's really hurting our community" ~ some person on TNB

Comment: @HyperNeutrino https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=37519058#37519058

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user who posted that challenge was destroyed as a sockpuppet account, which as a side effect deleted all of its content.

Needless to say, this is rather unfair to the users who posted the 40+ legitimate solutions. I've undeleted the challenge.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to consider the poster being deleted because I forget users can be deleted. Interesting. :P

Comment: so, a "normal" user deletion wouldn't trigger the Community to delete the question too, right?

Comment: @Rod That's right, *delete* and *destroy* are two separate options, the former of which only removes content with a negative score.

Comment: @Doorknob [Similar scenario](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121320/34718). I voted to undelete. Is there a way to look at what questions were deleted by Community yesterday?

Comment: It seems to have happened again, Doorknob; I just lost some rep from a user being deleted.

Comment: @Shaggy That's inevitable. When users get deleted for *any* reason, the votes they've cast are invalidated.